# Scraping dynamic dropdown with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping

I woud like a bit of help with the following. I am trying to scrape the elements of the tickers' dropdown on this website: https://live.hxro.io/tixwix

My code is as follow using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://live.hxro.io/tixwix"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\geckodriver\chromedriver.exe',options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

tickers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('lastprice-toggle')

tickers[0].text
```

This will only return

```
'BTC\nLast Price\n$39,255.07'
```

As it is an Ajax call I am not sure how to retrieve the other tickers in an efficient way. I thought the function find_element's' will return all the elements into a list but I only get the first one `tickers[1]` is out of bound.

Screenshot of the page source:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA7Sj.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works fine on my local :

**Explanation** :

You need to `click on accept cookies` button and shall try with `ExplicitWait` plus you would need to click on a svg icon which is there in your drop down (**XPATH** : `//span[text()='Last Price']/../following-sibling::*`).

In the end `span.moon` contains all the elements that you are looking for.

**Code :**

```
executablePath = r'C:\geckodriver.exe'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://live.hxro.io/tixwix")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Last Price']/../following-sibling::*"))).click()
sleep(5)
for values in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.moon"):
    print(values.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

**output :**

```
$39,321.02
$39,321.02
$8,728.5
$0.31063
$2,435.337
$24.232
$40.99
$8.9730
$22.685
$37,234.01
&nbsp;HIGHER
<span class="tooltip-text">CLOSE ABOVE</span>
(CLOSE ABOVE)
(TOUCH)
 $100,000
14.20X
 $100,000
1000.05X
 $68,000
152.69X
 $66,000
127.38X
 $64,000
117.34X
 $63,000
112.25X
 $62,000
105.95X
 $61,000
4.490X
 $60,000
92.80X
 $44,000
4.790X

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the an error with your code. ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="chevron-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-down fa-w-14 fa-1x dropdown-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">...</svg> is not clickable at point (490, 204).

Comment: This is strange.. it works just fine on my machine

Comment: Do you have `driver.maximize_window()` ?

Comment: I got the above output, should work for you.

Comment: Hi, sorry it works now. My bad I stuck to chrome as I was working with it at the start. I now switched to firefox and it works. Thank you

Comment: @Rahan : Yeah I was wondering why it did not work. Feel free to close this ticket by accepting any answer that was helpful to you

Comment: Thank you, both answers are very helpful actually.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. You should add

```
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

2. You should add a wait / delay
3. You should open the drop list
4. use correct locator to get elements in the drop list
   **UPD**
   5)In case of `ElementClickInterceptedException` click it with JavaScript. Not the best practice, but will work.
   I Think the code should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://live.hxro.io/tixwix"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\geckodriver\chromedriver.exe',options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

last_price_toggle = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.lastprice-toggle')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", last_price_toggle)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.lastprice-item')))

tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.lastprice-item span.moon')
for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker.text)
```

Comment: Like cruisepandey's code I get an error. ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="lastprice-toggle">...</div> is not clickable at point (399, 203). Other element would receive the click: <div style="position: absolute; display: flex; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; z-index: 101; background-color: rgb(19, 19, 21); text-align: center; align-items: center; font-size: 7vw; line-height: 7vw; color: gray;">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.106)

Comment: Hi Prophet, as per above I have switched to firefox and the code is now working. Sorry for the troubles. Thank you